# How to use between operator using dynamic content in adf sql server source dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have sql server as source which has a column "create_ts" in UTC. I'm trying to use copy data to adls by using the below query:

```
@concat('select * from dbo.table where create_ts between',' '',utcnow(),'' ','and',' '',subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 1, 'Day'),'' ')
```

The above query is throwing error `Missing comma between arguments`. If I remove the ' ' for dates then the actual query is failing. How to escape ' character or alternative to use this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this SQL:

```
select * from dbo.table where create_ts between '@{substring(utcnow(),0,23)}' and '@{substring(addDays(utcnow(),1),0,23)}'
```

I have tried this and it can work fine.
[image]